# Horizontal bounding of view in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a layout where a TextView (of variable width) needs to be able to move horizontally across the full bounds of the parent (based on data and view events).

What I've done to try to achieve this is use a ConstraintLayout with a Guideline. The Guideline has a `app:layout_constraintGuide_percent` constraint which I tweak between 0 and 1 programmatically, and the TextView is constrained `layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf` and `layout_constraintStart_toStartOf` to that Guideline.

The problem here is that when that guideline's `percent` nears 0 or 1 (around 0.05 and 0.95 respectively, in my case), the TextView starts disappearing past the bounds of the view.

In iOS, I would've created a higher-priority constraint restricting the TextView to the parent's bounds, but that doesn't quite seem to be a possibility using Android ConstraintLayout?

Full layout file:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    >
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textview"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:paddingBottom="5dp"
      android:visibility="visible"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guideline"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      tools:text="Variable text!"
      />

  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="300dp"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview"
      />
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
      android:id="@+id/guideline"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"
      />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What should happen when the text reaches the end? Should the sides be a hard stop for the `TextView` so it doesn't advance even as the guidelines pushes closer to the edge?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 vertical guidelines and constraint your textView to both of them so that when 1 guideline will move so is the other and your textView will remain in your screen bounds.

**Here is an example(feel free to move the guidelines to 0.95 and 0.05):**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Fragments.MenusDesign.ExpandableCategoriesMenu.ExpandableCategoriesMenu"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="Variable text!" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textview"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.0" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.18" />
```

Another thing you can do is to use [this library](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=473) to make sure that your text will resize itself according to the remaining space:

If you want to use this library **add this to your gradle:**

```
  implementation 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
```

**And now just create your textView:**

```
<me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:singleLine="true"
android:maxLines="2"
android:textSize="40sp"
autofit:minTextSize="16sp"
/>
```